# How can nodes fail

Tags: parity, nodes, network

I am writing plans to support a parity blockchain cluster and need to determine guidelines for the DevOps team.

What are the ways in which nodes can fail and back practice for handling these?

Comment: what do you mean by 'fail'?

Comment: Fall out of sync, go offline etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hardware failure
2. Disk full errors
3. Database integrity failure (due to reading damaged sector from disk), you will need to resync the blockchain again since you won't be able to continue adding new blocks
4. Spam attack (only solved by Ethereum Foundation)
5. DDoS from hackers

In short: for production use 2 nodes at least because you can't backup Level DB database while it is being used.